# How to create relationship to just one node (with a similar name) in neo4j cypher?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, relation

I want to design a Database about airports. Every airport has at least five terminals (named A, B, C, D and E). So I want to have Airport Schiphol INCLUDES A, B, C, D,E.  But I have created five terminals with the name "A" and thus if I run this code:

```
MATCH (a:Airport{name:"Schiphol"}),(b:Terminal{name:"A"}) CREATE (a)-[r: INCLUDES]->(b)
```

it attaches every Terminal A to Schiphol. How can I avoid this, and assign just 1 set of A , B, C, D and E to the airport?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MERGE is going to be the solution here, creating the pattern of the airport including a terminal, but not creating the :Terminal nodes ahead of time.

When you use MERGE for a pattern and one of the nodes is already bound (the :Airport node) and other isn't (the :Terminal), then if the pattern needs to be created the unbound node will be created along with the relationship between the nodes. This is how you create terminals per airport.

```
MATCH (a:Airport{name:"Schiphol"})
MERGE (a)-[:INCLUDES]->(termA:Terminal{name:"A"})
```

And if you want to create all the terminals at once per airport:

```
MATCH (a:Airport{name:"Schiphol"})
UNWIND ['A','B','C','D','E'] as term
MERGE (a)-[:INCLUDES]->(terminal:Terminal{name:term})
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. it worked. I tried to do the same, but then to create some gates per terminal. For example all terminal 'A's would gave three gates, either 'boarding' or 'closed'. But when I run this code:

Comment: MATCH (a:Terminal{name:"A"})
UNWIND ['Boarding','Closed','Closed'] as gate
MERGE (a)-[:BELONGS]->(g:Gate{name:gate})

it just creates two nodes and ignores the name which is put in twice ('Closed') . Why is this? @InverseFalcon

Comment: MERGE is like a MATCH followed by a CREATE if the match didn't match any existing paths. Since you were using the same value, it created the boarding gate and the closed gate, then matched to the just-created closed gate. If you just want to create all new nodes/relationships, use CREATE instead of MERGE.

Answer (score 0):

Why having five terminals with 'A' name ?
A solution can be :

```
MATCH (a:Airport{name:"Schiphol"})
MATCH (b:Terminal{name:"A"}) 
WITH a, COLLECT (b) as terminals
WITH a, HEAD(terminals) as terminal 
CREATE (a)-[r: INCLUDES]->(terminal)
```

(not tried)
But it is arbitrary...

Comment: because in reality you also have terminals with the same name in different places